# Copy to clipboard option for IE9, IE11 and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari, cross-browser

I am trying to implement a copy-to-clipboard button on a webpage. Below is the code I have written

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
   var $temp = $("<input>");
   $("body").append($temp);
   $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
   $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>

   <p id="p1">Text1</p>
   <p id="p2">Text2</p>
   <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy Text1</button>
   <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy Text2</button>
   <br/><br/>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Paste here for test" />
```

However, this does not seem to work on **IE 9, 11** and **Safari**. Is there any change/alternate implementation I can use to implement this on my webpage.

Comment: Answer will get from link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958441/copy-to-clipboard-for-ie-almost-working)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about Safari, but on IE you can do:

```
window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'text you want to copy goes here');
```

I hope it helps. Cheers